# Order of DynamoDB initialization impacts Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-ses

When sending mails through SES service I am running into the following error message spewed out by SES's sendEmail method.

```
{ [XMLParserError: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char: {]
  message: 'Non-whitespace before first tag.\nLine: 0\nColumn: 1\nChar: {',
  code: 'XMLParserError',
  retryable: true,
  time: Thu Sep 29 2016 15:34:20 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
  statusCode: 500 }
```

After quite a bit of debugging I have narrowed down that the problem is related the order of initialization of DynamoDB and SES objects. The following test code reproduces the problem:

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});

//var ses = new AWS.SES();    // This works
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
AWS.config.update({endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'});
var ses = new AWS.SES();    // Does not work

var params = {
    Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ['test@example.com']
    },
    Message: {
        Body: { 
            Html: {Data: "This is a test"},
            Text: {Data: "This is a test"}
        },
        Subject: {Data: "Important"}
    },
    Source: '<noreply@example.com>',
};

ses.sendEmail(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error sending email", err);
    }
    else 
        console.log("Sent email");
});
```

The above code sequence gives error. However, if I move the "var ses = new AWS.SES();" statement before DynamoDB then the code works. I am very curious to know what could be the cause

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the `AWS.config.update({endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'});` line that is messing up SES. Not the fact that it is coming after the DynamoDB line.

Comment: I just tried commenting that line and you are absolutely correct. Do you know the reason why this is the case?

Comment: It's setting the endpoint for all AWS services you initiate after that line. You don't have an SES endpoint running on your localhost, so that breaks SES.

Comment: Ok yes that makes sense - wish the error was more intuitive. Thanks for sharing your comments

Comment: Yes, setting `AWS.config.update({endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'})` in order to get Dynamodb to run creates the cryptic "XMLParserError". How then should a local dev box be set up for SES + Dynamodb?

Comment: Have suggested a cleanish solution in an answer below

Answer (score 1):

In your config.update put these

```
accessKeyId: 'any_values', 
secretAccessKey: 'any_values'
```

when you are working local development

Answer (score 1):

Yes- the documentation says to do `AWS.config.update({endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'})` in order to get DynamoDB working locally. However this is actually pretty bad advice, since `aws-sdk` cannot be intantiated into discrete objects. This means that setting `endpoint` for AWS in one place in your application will actually set `endpoint` for every single variable that you have `require`-d `aws-sdk` into, thereby breaking any AWS services (such as SES) that use another endpoint.

The correct solution seems to be to set `endpoint` for DynamoDB without "polluting" settings for other AWS services like so:

```
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
  region: 'eu-west-1',
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'         // <- set endpoint here
})
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  service: dynamodb
})
```